# @Java : Split String by First character Zeros

Tags: java

I have below String. How i can split this example string to Array like Output?

**Example String :**

> ```
> 000M10000100001
> ```

**Output : Split it to**

> ```
> String[]{"000M1","00001", "00001"}
> ```

Comment: split using regex that says string ends with 1. Though you could have many possibilities there. Ensure what possible instance of a string you could have and device the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"000M10000100001".split("(?<=1)(?=0)")
```

use lookbehind with lookahead to specify the position(end with 1).

https://regex101.com/r/aG9uP3/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex for splitting on "borders" when a non-zero is followed by zero, like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=[^0])(?=0.)");
String[] ss = p.split("000M10000100010");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/aRXSai)

The first part of expression `(?<=[^0])` means "preceded by non-zero".
The second part of expression `(?=0.)` means "followed by zero and some other character."

Comment: if i got this string :- "00M10000300010" it will be returns => String[ ] {"00M1", "00003", "0001","0"  }. but the correct answer that i want is -> String[ ] {"00M1", "00003", "00010"  }. the function  should be not check last chracter .

Comment: @Ryan Why did you un-accept when the other answer has exactly the same problem? This is an easy fix, please take a look at the edit.